# Is it possible to have a dynamic selector in jq using shell variables?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am curious if it is possible to have a shell variable like:

```sh
SEARCH=".[] | select(.notes[] | select(.body|contains("[SOMETEXT]")))"
```

and use that variable in a `jq` selection, like:

```sh
jq '${SEARCH}' input.json
```

For reference / testing the following JSON kan be used:

```
[
  {
    "id": 74892374923,
    "notes": [
      {
        "id": 8902348023,
        "body": "Some normal text"
      },
      {
        "id": 8094328420,
        "body": "Some more normal text"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 729384872903,
    "notes": [
      {
        "id": 0983012,
        "body": "Some more more normal text [SOMETEXT]"
      },
      {
        "id": 89023432,
        "body": "Some more more more normal text"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing approach define the filter definition in single quotes, to preserve the *literal* value and not to lose quotes or force any unnecessary variable expansion by the shell. Foe e.g. `"$var"` expands to a value stored in the place-holder `var`, but `'$var'` is stored as a plain string.

```
SEARCH='.[] | select(.notes[] | select(.body|contains("[SOMETEXT]")))'
jq "$SEARCH" json
```

Remember that you need to always escape double-quotes nested inside one other for it to be preserved. You are much better-off using an array and use the quoted expansion of type `array[*]` to produce a single word string to use as the filter. Any other ways using the shell variable would probably probably involve word-splitting/quote-removal done by the shell before even passing to the `jq` command.

With the array expansion the quotes are preserved and the only thing you need to ensure is *not* to modify the input field separator `IFS` value from its default.

```
ary=('.[]' '|' 'select(.notes[] | select(.body|contains("[SOMETEXT]")))')
jq "${ary[*]}" json
```